# How to find a pattern in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, stdvector

Is there any direct way of finding if a certain set of values (pattern) is present in a `std::vector` container?

Let's say I have this container of data:

```
std::vector<int> data { 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15 };
```

And this pattern described using another `std::vector` container:

```
std::vector<int> pattern { 0x00, 0xff, 0x00 };
```

I want:

- A boolean value that represents the presence of the pattern.
- Eventually, the index at which the pattern starts.

Comment: Something with a lambda and `std::find()` probably.

Comment: Please show input and desired output.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj We have been given the input and desired output though?

Comment: Take a look at [std::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search).

Comment: Why do I get three down votes? Please justify the reason, otherwise I can't figure what's wrong with the way I asked this question, thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `std::search`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data {0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15};
    std::vector<int> pattern {0x00, 0xff, 0x00};

    auto res = std::search(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::begin(pattern), std::end(pattern));
    if(res == std::end(data)) {
        std::cout << "Couldn't find it.\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Found it.\n";
    }
}
```

Here, `res` is an iterator pointing to the beginning of the sequence. If it's equal to the end of the haystack, there was no needle.

Comment: Do you know how could I find multiple occurencies? Lets say that a pattern occurs 2 times in data?

Comment: @TomazMazej You can use `std::count`. It's not a drop-in replacement, but it can help.

Comment: std::count only count number of ocurencies, but I would like to know the position of patterns just like in std::search, but std::search only returns the first position. Example: 
data: 10001
result: 0, 4